# Why can't I fast travel?

Tags: lego-jurassic-world

I've unlocked several map points in Jurassic World, and I can spot the difference between unlocked and and locked map points (they're greyed out), but the only option when I select a map point from the world map is to set a waypoint. How do I fast travel to these map points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast travel seems to only be available within a movie's area once you've completed that movie's story mode. After you get the dinosaur credits scene for that movie, you will get a `Travel to Area` prompt when you select a map point you have unlocked.

In some cases, backtracking to unlock a map point you had missed is also restricted because of gates that are locked while you're progressing through the movie's story.